# Storing and querying undirected many-to-many relationships

Tags: sql, database

I've come across a database schema which contains the following relations:

Person ( ID, name )
Friend ( ID1, ID2 )

ID1 and ID2 are foreign keys of Person.ID

Friend is an undirected relationship (i.e. it's bidirectional). In the schema, for a given friendship from ID 123 to ID 456 this is stored as two tuples: (123, 456) and (456, 123).

It seems to me that to store a single conceptual entity in two tuples is not good: the data can potentially become inconsistent; and there's duplication in the dataset.

Unless I'm mistaken, it should be possible to do everything we want to do with the database, even if there's only one tuple. In the worst case, the version of the table can be easily recreated:

```
SELECT *
FROM Friend
UNION
SELECT ID2 as ID1, ID1 as ID2
FROM Friend
```

So my question is: what's best practise in storing undirected many-to-many relationships? And why?

If it is the case that storing the information in two tuples is the best way of doing things, would it be better for INSERT INTO, UPDATE and DELETE queries to change both records, or to rely on triggers to maintain consistency?

Comment: You don't need to store two tuples here. You can do everything you want by storing just one relationship. You will have to modify your queries to check for both directions, that's all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, in most databases, I might go for one row for the `Friends` table with the following two conditions:

- unique index on id1, id2
- check constraint that id1 < id2

But, in MySQL you cannot implement check constraints.  Because you have to resort to triggers, you might as well have insert/update/delete triggers that manage the duplicate rows.

There are advantages and disadvantages to both approaches.  For instance, for the first, you need to be careful about the ordering of values for inserts.  Or, you need a trigger.  Or, what I would normally do anyway, is have a stored procedure that wraps database changes and takes care of the proper insert order.  And, fetching all the friends of X requires a more complicated query.

The second approach uses more space, which can be cumbersome.  But, it more easily answers questions such as "who are the friends of your friends".  But there is more overhead on insertion and updates.

In the end, it really depends on what kind of queries you will want to run.